# Solaris 9 - Word Count (wc) command gives wrong output with 'grep -v and ps'

Tags: solaris, ps, wc

When i use **'ps', 'egrep'** and **'wc'** command to count number of processes, it gives me wrong value. I am running the command in **'Solaris 9'** machine.

```
MyServer $ ps -fu root | egrep -v 'bash|ksh|ssh|ef|mailx|nohup|defunct|ps|sh|FND'
     UID   PID  PPID  C    STIME TTY      TIME CMD
 root 16267 16171  0   Jan 28 ?        0:18 xyz
 root 16269 16171  0   Jan 28 ?        0:07 abc
 root 16268 16171  0   Jan 28 ?        0:07 ghi
MyServer $
```

Only 4 (3 processes + header) lines shown in output. But when i use below command it returns the output as **5**

```
MyServer $ ps -fu root | egrep -v 'bash|ksh|ssh|ef|mailx|nohup|defunct|ps|sh|FND' | wc -l
       5
```

On the otherhand, when I echo the output to a file and count the number of lines, it works perfectly normal.

```
MyServer $ ps -fu root | egrep -v 'bash|ksh|ssh|ef|mailx|nohup|defunct|ps|sh|FND' >temp && cat temp | wc -l
       4
```

**More description related to 'egrep' and 'egrep -v':**

Why does 'egrep' working properly without '-v' option? But not with '-v'?

```
MyServer$ ps -fu root | egrep '20755|13800'
 root 20755 20751  0 12:14:29 pts/5    0:00 more -s /tmp/mpWGa4mO
 root  1223 26407  0 12:57:28 pts/15   0:00 egrep 20755|13800
MyServer$ ps -fu root | egrep '20755|13800' | wc -l
       2
MyServer$

MyServer$ ps -fu root | egrep -v 'usr|apps|sql|sh'
     UID   PID  PPID  C    STIME TTY      TIME CMD
 root  3448 26407  0 12:57:42 pts/15   0:00 ps -fu root
 root 20755 20751  0 12:14:29 pts/5    0:00 more -s /tmp/mpWGa4mO
MyServer$ ps -fu root | egrep -v 'usr|apps|sql|sh' | wc -l
       4
MyServer$
```

Comment: ... is `wc` a process?

Comment: on a side note, there is a funny option of grep that is `-c` ....

Comment: The problem seems to be with 'egrep -v' option. Question has been modified with details that supports the issue.

Comment: @jass, when you redirected the grep result to file before wc -l.The result will be different.You should put wc -l before you redirected to file.When you used wc -l after the result file.That meant wc -l counted on file.

Answer (score -1):

`wc -l` counts new line characters. There may be more new line characters than lines with meaningful data in your output.

For example. Create a file with a line but without a newline character:

```
$ cat > test.txt
hello # Type CTRL+D (2 times are necessary on my system)

$ wc -l < test.txt
0
```